# Is it possible to make Notepad++'s UI tab width constant, instead of responsive to filenames? (NOT the Tab character)

Tags: user-interface, tabs, notepad++, filenames

For some reason Notepad++'s UI tab width (not the Tab character, the literal UI tab) responds to the length of file names. This could probably be handy, but for me it's just annoying because I have a small screen, and longer file names means fewer tabs available at a time, so I have to keep scrolling back and forth even though I only have a handful of files opened. Is there any setting for UI tab width to be constant as in most other programs? To be clear, renaming files for shorter names is not an option.

Comment: It seems that capability is not offered, but another option that is available is setting the tab bar multi-line, so that it would stack them to avoid scrolling back and forth. However, depending on how many tabs would make the viewable document area shorter.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be a currently implemented feature, however if you are able to sacrife some screen real estate on the side you could try the Document list panel.

Under Settings > Preferences, check "Hide" in the Tab Bar section and check "Show" and "Disable extension column" in the Document List Panel Section. This essentially gives you a vertical tab bar that can be moved around or attached to the side.